# Creating a smooth transition between materials on large models using Unity and/or Blender

Tags: unity, textures, blender, 3d-modeling

I'm not sure if this is possible or not but I would like to create a smooth transition (cross-fade) between two textures on a 3D model made in Blender that can be imported to Unity.

For example if I have a model with two materials, the edges where the materials meet is an abrupt change. How would I go about creating a smooth transition across the edge where the materials meet?

I've seen some tutorials on using cycles in Blender to achieve this, but to the best of knowledge the cycles rendering cannot be brought into Unity.  Projection painting in Blender using an image as the brush is also a possibility, but the models I'm trying to do this on are rather large and would lose resolution in their textures because of this.  Is something like Substance Painter by Allegarithmic what I need?

Comment: I have to assume that his is possible because of the way that tri-planar texturing works in which two textures can be blended based on the "projection" angle.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the materials you need to blend and how they're mapped? This might be as simple as a 2-texture material with a cross-fade control value baked into the UVs/vertex colours, or arbitrarily more complicated, depending on the output you need.